# fprintf Android NDK

Tags: c, android-ndk

Anyone know of a possible reason why fprintf maynot work for me when using the android NDK?

```
FILE * f = fopen("/sdcard/newfile.txt", "w+");
fprintf(f, "testing\n");
```

I do have the write external storage permission in the android manifest. And this code creates a file newfile.txt but it's empty.

Is there anything else that has to be done to let me write stuff to a file?

Comment: Did you call `fflush` or `fclose` ? Did you test that `fprintf` returns a positive value? Did you test `errno` (or call `perror`) otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to close the stream with something like "fclose":

```
FILE * f = fopen("/sdcard/newfile.txt", "w+");
fprintf(f, "testing\n");
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I totally forgot about fclose... too much python ruby lately:p